# How to use a typed Scala Trait in generic function?

Tags: scala, generics, types

```
scala> trait BaseTrait[T] { def foo(e: T): String}
defined trait BaseTrait

scala> class C1 extends BaseTrait[String] {def foo(e: String) = "C1"}
defined class C1

scala> class C2 extends BaseTrait[Int] {def foo(e: Int) = e.toString}
defined class C2

scala> def general(e :BaseTrait) = {println(e.foo())}
<console>:43: error: trait BaseTrait takes type parameters
`enter code here`def general(e :BaseTrait) = {println(e.foo())}
```

That defeats polymorphic behavior...how do I define generic functions that consume BaseTrait?

Comment: `def general(e :BaseTrait[_])` but this is still not going to work. `e.foo` takes parameters. Check parametric polymorphism, it seems you want ad hoc polymorphism.

Comment: @user7938511 You conveniently didn't specify where you were going to get a valid argument to pass to `foo` without parametrizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One valid definition of `general` would be

```
def general[A](e: BaseTrait[A], a: A) = println(e.foo(a))
```